# Calculate periods and average sum where balance was positive

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm stuck with window function.

I have this table called **task**:

user_id VARCHAR
date DATE
balance INTEGER

```
+---------+------------+---------+
| user_id |    date    | balance |
+---------+------------+---------+
|       1 | 03.04.2020 |       0 |
|       1 | 04.04.2020 |     265 |
|       1 | 05.04.2020 |     140 |
|       1 | 06.04.2020 |      70 |
|       1 | 07.04.2020 |       0 |
|       2 | 03.04.2020 |     535 |
|       2 | 04.04.2020 |     115 |
|       2 | 05.04.2020 |       0 |
|       2 | 06.04.2020 |       0 |
|       2 | 07.04.2020 |     694 |
+---------+------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to calculate all the periods where balance was constantly positive. 
So the output table should look like this:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | start_date |  end_date  | avg_balance | date_length |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | 04.04.2020 | 06.04.2020 | 158.3       |           3 |
|       2 | 03.04.2020 | 04.04.2020 | 325         |           2 |
|       2 | 07.04.2020 | 07.04.2020 | 694         |           1 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I've tried to implement the window function but got stuck.

Comment: Are you using SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: I'm using SQLite. Sorry for not mentioning. 
So I suppose that's the reason your answer isn't working for me

Comment: . . No, the `where` clause had a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign periods by counting the number of zeros before.  Then aggregate:

```
select user_id, min(date), max(date), avg(balance), count(*) as date_length
from (select t.*,
             sum( balance = 0 ) over (partition by user_id order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where balance > 0
group by user_id, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b7e4b1ac2a84bb4e8708db7ca041b32c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: `where balance = 0` should be `where balance > 0`